# My page divs are not at the same level

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I have those 2 div inside my page where they look like:

[image]

The add appointment div should be at the same line of the first div and I don't know why it looks like this.

Here is my code for first div:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6">
  <div class="info-box box box-default">
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <button id="collapse" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>
                <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i></span>
                <div class="info-box-content">
                  <span class="info-box-text">Today's appointments</span>
                  <span class="label label-primary" id="numApp"><?php echo $numApp ?></span>

                </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
                <?php if($numApp != 0) { ?>
              <div class="box" id="toggleDiv">  
                <div class="box-body">
                  <table style="text-align:center" id="appTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">

                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Patient</th>
                        <th>Reason</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php foreach($appResFetch as $row){ ?>
                        <tr id="<?php echo $row['app_id']; ?>">
                          <td><?php echo $row['time_app'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['date_app'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['patient_name'] ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['reason'] ?></td>
                          <td><button id="appDel" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button></td>
                </form>
              </div><!-- /.box -->
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                  </table>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->
              <?php } ?>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
        </section><!-- /.content -->
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    </div><!-- /.info-box -->
</div>
```

And here is the code for the second one:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6">
  <div class="info-box box box-default">
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <button id="collapse" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>
                <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></span>
                <div class="info-box-content">
                  <span class="info-box-text">Add appointment</span>
                  <span class="label label-primary" id="numApp"><?php echo $numApp ?></span>
                </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
              <div class="box" id="toggleDiv">  
                <div class="box-body">
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
        </section><!-- /.content -->
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're wrapping your columns inside proper rows?

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh Doesn't look like it.

Comment: Wouldn't a nesting of the two divs be a proper approach here, you could apply a _col-md-6_ to both of them right ?

Comment: Yeah, I have the global div is `<div class="box"` and it is from `fontAwesome` library, should I add a new div where `class="row"` ?